# Sort List of foreign keys by value-property of dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have an `Dictionary<int, Person>` with data of persons (read from Microsoft SQL Server). Key is the ID of the Person.

In an function I get an List with a bunch of IDs of persons. Now I can loop through this List and print out this subset of persons.

```cs
foreach(int ID in PersonsList)
{
  Console.write(PersonsDictionary[ID].FullName);
}
```

The Problem now is, that whether the Dictionary nor the List are orderd in any way, but I want the Persons in an alphabetical order. So how can I sort my List of IDs by the FullName-Property of the Value of the Dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> sortedNames = 
    PersonsList
        .Select(id => PersonsDictionary[id].FullName) // Select the name for each entry
        .OrderBy(n => n, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // Order the names (case insenstive)

foreach(string name in sortedNames) // Materialize the ordered names
{
    Console.Write(name); // print
}
```

You might need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs file for this to work, since it uses LINQ extension methods:

- [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)
- [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__)

Note that, like your original code, this will throw a KeyNotFoundException if `PersonsList` contains a key that doesn't exist in `PersonsDictionary`.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/KDSAE95916)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I made a little Change to get a sorted list of IDs instead of Names, but this gave me the necessary hint. `Select(ID => PersonsDictionary[ID].ID) .OrderBy(n => PersonsDictionary[n].Fullname, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` I know about the KeyNotFoundException, but this is no Problem, because I get the list by a foreach with some "if" from the Dictionary.